# Convert for loop scraping into pool parallel scraping?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, parallel-processing, python-requests, scrapy

I am trying to download PubMed articles from the official website. I am using requests to query and store the data but since the data is too large I want to run multiple workers instead of just one, currently, I am using for loop.

My current code looks like this :

```
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
import json

search_url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&mindate=1800/01/01&maxdate=2020/10/31&usehistory=y&retmode=json"
search_r = requests.post(search_url)
search_data = search_r.json()
webenv = search_data["esearchresult"]['webenv']
total_records = int(search_data["esearchresult"]['count'])
fetch_url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmax=9999&query_key=1&webenv="+webenv

for i in tqdm(range(0, total_records, 10000)):
    this_fetch = fetch_url+"&retstart="+str(i)
    print("Getting this URL: "+this_fetch)
    fetch_r = requests.post(this_fetch)
    f = open('./pubmed_data/pubmed_batch_'+str(i)+'_to_'+str(i+9999)+".json", 'w')
    f.write(fetch_r.text)
    f.close()

print("Number of records found :"+str(total_records))
```

How I can speed up my scraping process? Thank you!

Comment: use threading or multiprocessing ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the multiprocessing module

```
import multiprocessing
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
import json


search_url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&mindate=1800/01/01&maxdate=2020/10/31&usehistory=y&retmode=json"
search_r = requests.post(search_url)
search_data = search_r.json()
webenv = search_data["esearchresult"]['webenv']
total_records = int(search_data["esearchresult"]['count'])
fetch_url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmax=9999&query_key=1&webenv="+webenv

def many_requests():
    this_fetch = fetch_url + "&retstart=" + str(i)
    print("Getting this URL: " + this_fetch)
    fetch_r = requests.post(this_fetch)
    f = open('./pubmed_data/pubmed_batch_' + str(i) + '_to_' + str(i + 9999) + ".json", 'w')
    f.write(fetch_r.text)
    f.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in tqdm(range(0, total_records, 10000)):
        multiprocessing.Process(target=many_requests()).start()


print("Number of records found :"+str(total_records))
```